# Bulk loading SalesForce Files

Tags: data, migration, files

I need to load around 250 GB of files from a local SAN into SalesForce. I have tried using dataloader to push blobs of the files into the ContentVersion object - but because of the size and volume dataloader gives me the Java Heap Space error.

I have tried referencing the files with 'PathOnClient' - but this gives the same error (I guess dataloader just converts the file to a blob/binary)

What have people used to move large amounts of files to SalesForce?

Comment: Have you tried reducing the batch size in Settings?

Answer (score 1):

You should us batch size as 1 or 2 to load the files into Salesforce through dataloader.

Just a note Bulk API is not supported to import blob data.

Comment: Thanks, have you tried to load a similar quantity yourself, using this method?